# Laravel get Eloquent relation by same name as its attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have database tables like this:

```
shoot: id, name, programme
programme: id, name
```

The eloquent relationship in the shoot is defined like this:

```
public function programme() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Programme', 'programme', 'id');
}
```

When using `dd()`, I can see this is working correctly:

```
dd(Shoot:where('id','=',1)->with('programme')->first());
// prints the object with programme listed under the relationship
```

However when I eager-load the shoot and attempt to get the programme object, I retrieve the shoot attribute "programme" instead. E.g.:

```
$shoot = Shoot:where('id','=',1)->with('programme')->first();
echo $shoot->programme; // returns 1, not App\Programme object.
```

Is there a solution to this without having to rewrite masses of the codebase?

Comment: This is because your relationship has the same name as one of your attributes. It returns your attribute instead.

Comment: Stick to the naming conventions `programme` - `programme_id` and you should be good to go... What is programme anyway? Use English while coding. (google flagged it as wrongly spelled word)

Comment: It is "proper English" ;) - British English spelling of programme, e.g. a television programme. Program in British English refers to software programs explicitly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same name for the both `relationship` and `column` name, else you'll receive always the `column` name so try to edit one of them, I think the easiest one here is the `relationship` name  :

```
public function programmeObj() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Programme', 'programme', 'id');
}
```

Then call it as :

```
echo $shoot->programmeObj;
```

**NOTE :** But if you want to follow conventions you should replace the name attribute by `programme_id` so :

```
public function programme() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Programme', 'programme_id', 'id');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wanted to avoid renaming every reference to attributes throughout code as the codebase is giant at this stage. However, I decided this would be the best option. It is good to know a simple workaround is to just rename the model function.

Answer (score 8):

To achieve what you after you will need to do the following:

```
$shoot = Shoot:where('id','=',1)->with('programme')->first();
$variable = $shoot->programme; // returns 1
$obj = $page->getRelationValue('programme') // returns App\Programme object.
```

Answer (score 3):

This will returns always the column in your database if it exists, that's ID 1.

When you call `dump($shoot);` you should get the array with all attributes. But when you run the following you should get the name:

Your model:

```
public function programmeData() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Programme', 'programme', 'id');
}
```

And your controller:

```
$shoot = Shoot:where('id','=',1)->first();
return $shoot->programmeData->name; // returns name
```

Hope this works!

Comment: This is not working for me, calling dd($shoot->programmeData)  - returns "null". UPDATE - sorry misunderstood the model changes, this is a good work around for now - thanks!

Comment: What did you changed?

Comment: @kirgy nice, another solution is to change the `shoot -> programme` column to `programma_id`. Than you can use the other answer from Zakaria.