# Retrieve relationship items from a collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

In a controller I create a collection with:

```
$playershome = App\Team::where('id', $session->team1_id)->with('players')->first();
```

and call my view with:

```
        return view('member.home', compact('user', 'session', 'playershome', 'playersaway'));
```

In my Team model I've:

```
    public function players(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_users');
}
```

The collection is created:

[image: Team Collection]

But I don't know how to retrieve "players" item in my view.
I try with:

```
@foreach($playershome->players as $player)
```

But I got:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

What wrong?

UPDATE view:

```
                                            <div class="mt-body">
                                            <h3 class="mt-body-title"> {{$session->team1Id->name}} </h3>
                                            <p class="mt-body-description"> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted </p>
                                            <ul class="mt-body-stats">
                                                @foreach($playershome->players as $player)

                                                    <li class="font-green">
                                                        <img src="/storage/{{$player->avatar}}"></li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="mt-body-actions">
                                                <div class="btn-group btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">
                                                        <i class="icon-bubbles"></i> Punti </a>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn ">
                                                        <i class="icon-social-twitter"></i> K/D </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: can u add the view ?

Comment: View added in the question

Comment: change $playershome = App\Team::where('id', $session->team1_id)->with('players')->first();   to this:   $playershome = App\Team::where('id', $session->team1_id)->with('players')->get();

Comment: Just tried, this is the error with get: Property [players] does not exist on this collection instance / If I change $playershome with $playershome[0] in the foreach I got the same error Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: keep this: $playershome =Team->players()::where('id', $session->team1_id)->with('players')->get();    and edit foreach to this : foreach($playershome as $player)

Comment: In this way I don't have any errors but not scroll players items, inside the foreach I've the same collection that I've with ->first;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148242/discussion-between-leo-kelmendi-and-natas).

Comment: Add a `{{print_r($playershome->players)}} {{die;}}` to see what are you fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your chat that you had in the comments I see that you are using the same name for an attribute called `players` in your teams table, and also the relation to the users is called `players`. Try renaming the relation to something else, change it in your query and also in your foreach.

EDIT: Found stackoverflow question to the same issue as you: [Laravel get Eloquent relation by same name as its attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460707/laravel-get-eloquent-relation-by-same-name-as-its-attribute)

Comment: Yes the problem is a conflict with players column name and the relation method with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way round

```
$playershome = App\Team::with('players')->where('id', $session->team1_id)->get();
```