# Eager load when model has attribute with same name?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model that has an attribute called 'hm'. The same model has a method called 'hm' that handles relation to another table:

```
Class Page {

   public function hm() {
      returh $this->hasOne('App\Hm');
   }

}
```

So when I perform a query I may want to access attribute "hm" but I may also get "hm" the relation.

```
$page = \App\Page::with('hm')->first();
$variableHm = $page->hm;
$relationHm = $page->hm; # issue is here
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst there are some posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460707/laravel-get-eloquent-relation-by-same-name-as-its-attribute) suggesting that what I am after cannot be done I have identified a method within eloquent that allows you to get relation value. So, that can be achieved using method `getRelationValue()` and a line `$page->getRelationValue('hm')` will fetch my relation!