# can't display foreign key value in laravel blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show foreign key value in a blade. But I can't show I keep getting an error =

```
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDAPP\resources\views\products\index.blade.php)
```

Here is my migration file:

product migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category');
            $table->foreign('category')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer("quantity")->nullable();
            $table->boolean("is_out")->default(0);
        });
```

Category migration

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string("title");
        });
```

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "products";
    protected $fillable = [
        "product_name",
        "price",
        "category",
        "quantity",
        "is_out"
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "categories";
    protected $fillable = [
        "title"
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::with('category')->get();
        print_r($products);
        return view('products.index',[
            "products"=>$products
        ]);
    }
```

My blade:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>PRODUCTS NAME</th>
        <th>PRODUCTS PRICE</th>
        <th>PRODUCTS CATEGORY</th>
        <th>PRODUCTS STOCK</th>
        <th>PRODUCTS STATUS</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
            **<td>{{ $product->category->title }}</td>**
            <td>{{ $product->quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->is_out }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to show category title. I don't know why I am getting error. I have tried a lot of ways to solve it but can't figure the main problem. I am new laravel.

Comment: Won't this `$table->unsignedBigInteger('category');` mean that your product model already has a property named `category`, which is an int and not the referenced Category model?

Comment: I don't know what you are telling me. Can you explain more? I am new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel get Eloquent relation by same name as its attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460707/laravel-get-eloquent-relation-by-same-name-as-its-attribute)

Comment: When creating a method like your `category()` that defines the relationship, you can access the related data through: `$product->category`. However, since your `Product` model & database table already has the attribute `$product->category` (which I'm assuming is the category id), Laravel/PHP can't know which you want to access, the models original `category`-attribute (an integer for the category id), or the related object defined through the `category()`-method.

Comment: same error @M.Eriksson

Comment: After what? You never said what you changed. Basically, don't have an attribute and a method (defining some relationship) with the same names.

Comment: can you please give me code sample? Like can you fix the code? @M.Eriksson

Comment: I changed the methods name to productObj and categoryObj @M.Eriksson

Comment: Read the link I posted above. Then also read this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. I can't really explain it clearer than that.

Comment: This question already answered. You could search more to find the answer in SO.

Comment: Its not answered yet @EHFShahab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relation and column both have a name `category`. This will not work, so I suggest you rename the column to `category_id`, then the code will work as is.

Comment: But I get the id If write like this: $product->category

Comment: Right, missed the naming conflict! Edited the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Change `public function products()` to `public function product()` at your `Category` model.

You have an excess of the letter `s` at the end of the function name (product**s**), you must give the function name the exact same as the model you want to connect to, because the name of the model you want to connect to is `product`, then the name of the function that connects to that (`product`) model must also be `product` , unless you specify the foreign key as the second parameter in the method you write in the function

Comment: I did but still same @Mushlih Almibarak

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change like this :

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category', 'id);
}
```

This is `belongsTo` relationship

```
public function belongsTo(
    $related,
    $foreignKey = null,
    $ownerKey = null,
    $relation = null
) { }
@param string $related

@param string|null $foreignKey

@param string|null $ownerKey

@param string|null $relation
```